# Can I upgrade a Dell Inspiron One 2320 to Windows 10

Tags: upgrade

I would really love some input on how to best proceed here. I have a Dell Inspiron One 2320 with Windows 7 Home 64-bit. I wanted to upgrade to Windows 10. With the tool CPU-Z I was able to see that the CPU instructions had what I needed to upgrade to Windows 10 (SSE2, EM64T, VT-x). However, when I called Dell to confirm if I can upgrade, I was told not to move ahead. So I'm not sure how to proceed. I could use some input here how best to proceed. Another options was to consider upgrading to Windows 8 if Win 10 was iffy as the upgrade checker seemed for most part advise me that the system is upgradeable.

Here are the general specs for the Dell Inspiron One 2320 I wish to upgrade:

Operating System
Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1
CPU
Intel Core i5 2400S @ 2.50GHz 58 °C
Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology
RAM
6.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz (9-9-9-24)
Motherboard
Dell Inc. 050NT9 (CPU 1)
Graphics
23" AIO (1600x900@60Hz)
Intel HD Graphics (Dell)
1024MB NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M (Dell) 49 °C
Storage
931GB Seagate ST1000NM0033-9ZM173 ATA Device (SATA) 37 °C
931GB Western Digital WD My Passport 259F USB Device (USB (SATA)) 31 °C
29GB SanDisk Ultra USB Device (USB)
Optical Drives
MATSHITA DVD+-RW UJ8C1 ATA Device
Audio
Realtek High Definition Audio

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it can be done....https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron-Desktops/Inspiron-One-2320-Upgraded-to-Windows-10-need-drivers/td-p/6100431

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, any machine that runs Windows 7 should be able run Windows 10 without issue.  Heck, I havent seen a Windows XP machine that hasnt been able to be upgraded to 10.  Granted, being able to run and being able to run *well* is an function of its overall hardware.  The specs of your machine are more than capable of running Windows 10 smoothly.

If the Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant says you can upgrade, then all the hardware is compatible with Windows 10.  There is no reason you could not proceed.  However, it is a good idea to make an image/backup of your current Windows 7 OS and data, just to be safe.

I suspect Dell told you not to proceed is that ***they*** do not support Windows 10 on such an old machine.  Just because ***they*** dont support it, that does not mean it will not work.  This is understandable, as they cannot support every operating system that comes out on every machine they sell, even if it works.  It is simply too much work on their part.

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  However Dell says it's not a matter of them not supporting but hardware might not be able to run it smoothly.  Hummm, not quite sure that is true. I already installed Windows 10 on an older machine and it went fine.  But did not install drivers and software back so can not say with certainty.

I think I'll go with creating a clone of the hard drive and proceeding to try Windows 10.

I was never able to find the windows 10 upgrade assistant.  Just for Win 8.   If you are aware of any tool being able to verify compatibility other than the win 8 tool, I'd appreciate knowing where to find it.

Thank you for your help.
Eva